# Why does the Devil "glower" at Benedict Arnold's absence in "The Devil and Daniel Webster"?

Tags: short-stories, historical-context

The short story "[The Devil and Daniel Webster](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0602901.txt)" is filled with topical and historical references, and clearly has a moral opinion on colonial American history. Generally speaking, this moral opinion is clear and unabashed, but there is one passage I feel I am missing.

When the Devil assembles the jurors for Stone's trial, it's a hodgepodge of (mostly real, some fictional) famous traitors or villains from American history, with the obviously notable exception of Benedict Arnold, which is immediately commented upon in the story itself:

> "Are you satisfied with the jury, Mr. Webster?" said the stranger
> mockingly, when they had taken their places.
>
> The sweat stood upon Dan'l Webster's brow, but his voice was clear.
>
> "Quite satisfied," he said. "Though I miss General Arnold from the
> company."
>
> "Benedict Arnold is engaged upon other business," said the stranger,
> with a glower. "Ah, you asked for a justice, I believe."

I feel like I'm absolutely missing something here. The author is writing a moralistic tale about American history, contrives a situation where he has to list 12 notorious moral villains, declines to include the most famous example, and then points out the omission explicitly in the text with a very ambiguous-sounding explanation.

Why did the Devil "glower" at Arnold's absence? Is it because actually Arnold is *not* in Hell, but the Devil doesn't want to admit it? Or is Arnold so high-ranking in Hell that even the Devil himself wasn't able to press him into service on such short notice? Or is the "other business" a topical reference to something else happening at the time of the story, and it just flew over my head?

I don't know what the answer is, but I have a feeling the meaning was intended to be an obvious wink to the audience; this is not a subtle story. Hopefully somebody can point to the author's intention here.

Comment: Interesting to note that I think the film version does include Arnold in the jury.